# Where's Mr. Scratch coming in?

Tags: alan-wake

Answer to this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/help-me-to-understand-the-alan-wake-ending) mentions Mr. Scratch. I do not remember the name mentioned in the game, but I must have missed it.

Can someone please remind me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SPOILER ALERT]
(Please add spoiler indication to the question title.)

[This site](http://alanwake.wikia.com/wiki/Alan_Wake_(Character)) details the answer.

Here's the relevent text:

> Alan fights his way all across the
>   town, fighting and escaping from an
>   army of Taken and Poltergeists sent by
>   the Dark Presence to stop him. When
>   Alan arrives at Cauldron Lake, he
>   dives in to save Alice. But as soon as
>   he does so, he blacks out again. When
>   he awakes, he is at the bottom of the
>   lake. The Dark Presence tries stopping
>   him from finding the Clicker by using
>   hallucinations and tricks to get Alan
>   to give up. But Alan finds the Clicker
>   and uses it to drive the Darkness and
>   hallucinations away. Alan is visited
>   by Thomas Zane in a diver's suit, who
>   tells Alan that Barbara Jagger has no
>   heart, he must "fill it's heart with
>   light." Before Alan leaves to find
>   Jagger, Zane introduces Alan to Mr.
>   Scratch. Mr. Scratch is a clone of
>   Alan Wake who will return to the world
>   while Alan writes the ending to the
>   book. Zane leaves and Alan finds Bird
>   Leg Cabin under the lake.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this site.](http://alanwake.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Scratch) He was first mentioned in Episode 6: Departure after Alan destroys the tornado.